# How to get every image path inside a folder using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I create an array like this one below that stores all the paths of the images I have in a local folder using a loop instead of having to type all the paths myself?

```
 const imagePaths =
   [../images/img0, ../images/img1, ../images/img2, ../images/img3];
```

Comment: Are you doing this in node.js? Or in a browser?

Comment: There are many examples of walking a directory (or directory tree) and getting filenames, as well as multiple globbing modules--but browser vs. Node matters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry but I don't know yet what you mean by browser or node.js. At the moment I only have knowledge in html, CSS and JavaScript. It does not actually make any difference for me what I use my only goal is to get all image paths (more than a 100) without have to type all of them which will cause a lot of unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers javascript do not have privileges to access the local resources.

Comment: What would be the best option for me then at this point?  Should I write all the image names myself?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `require-all` module to get all files under a folder.

```
const requireAll = require('require-all');

let allFiles = requireAll({
    dirname: __dirname + '/'
});

console.log(allFiles);
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/0iL0b48Mo